# Error #1034, with a MouseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

I am making a basic point n' click game and I came upon this error:
**TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert 3 to cem.mouvement.**

Here's my script:

```
package cem {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import cem.microjeux.events.InfoJeuEvent;
    import cem.mouvement;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class monterJeu extends MovieClip
    {
        private static var pType:String = "type";
        private static var pNom:String = "testNom";
        private static var pCourriel:String = "test@hotmail.com";
        private static var pDifficulte:int = 0;
        private static var pLangue:int = 0;
        private static var pTitre:String = "Veuillez sortir";
        private static var pVersion:String = "1.5";
        private static var pCoordonnees:Number;

        private var environnementJeu:environnement = new environnement();
        private var personnageJeu:personnage = new personnage();

        public function monterJeu():void
        {
            jouer(pNom,pDifficulte,pLangue);
            dispatchEvent(new InfoJeuEvent(pType,pNom,pCourriel,pTitre,pVersion));
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, test);
        }

        public function jouer(PNom:String,PDifficulte:int,PLangue:int):void
        {
            addChild(environnementJeu);
            addChild(personnageJeu);
        }
        function test(e:MouseEvent){
            pCoordonnees = stage.mouseX;
            trace(pCoordonnees);
            mouvement(3);
        }
    }
}
```

And on mouvement();

```
package cem
{
    public class mouvement {

        public function mouvement(blabla) {
            trace(blabla);
        }
    }
}
```

I searched everywhere I could, and didn't find anything. I have no instances on the stage. Everything is imported on the first frame. I am kind of a beginner (let's say i'm no good at programming), so you can notify at the same time if you something that needs to be corrected. (BTW, the strange words are in french ;D)
Thanks!

Comment: If you properly format your code, it will make answering the question easier

Comment: yeah sorry, it doesn't want to format better than that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to you trying to cast 3 to mouvement.

I think what you want is something like

```
function test(e:MouseEvent){
    pCoordonnees = stage.mouseX;
    trace(pCoordonnees);
    var mouve:mouvement = new mouvement(3);
}
```

Notice that you have to have *new* in order to create a new instance of a class.

On another note, you should capitilize classes so they stand out better. So I would name the class Mouvement.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast `3` to the class `mouvement` into the `test` function:

```
   function test(e:MouseEvent){
        pCoordonnees = stage.mouseX;
        trace(pCoordonnees);
        new mouvement().mouvement(3); // <-- here your error
    }
```

If you have only a function into your class you don't need to create a class but you can put on the function alone:

```
package cem
{
        public function mouvement(blabla):void {
            trace(blabla);
        }
}
```

and now you can call the mpuvement function normally into you test function:

```
function test(e:MouseEvent){
    pCoordonnees = stage.mouseX;
    trace(pCoordonnees);
    mouvement(3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Wish I could put two correct answers... And thank you for formatting my text also! I didn't know that you could only put a function and no class.